# In std::set<boost::uuids::uuid>'s destructor, I got a segmentation fault (core dumped) in _int_free. Why?

Tags: c++, glibc

I am using a boost::shared_ptr to handle my class pointers.
And in my class, there is a member of type `std:set<boost::uuids::uuid>`.
I set this member value in initial code only once. And I have double check there is no buffer overflow.
I have run valgrind to check, and there is no memory error reports.

But, in my class destructor, I got a core dump in _int_free. This is it's callstack:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0098c02e in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x048ec552 in operator delete(void*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x08056372 in std::_Rb_tree<boost::uuids::uuid, boost::uuids::uuid, std::_Identity<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::less<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::allocator<boost::uuids::uuid> >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<boost::uuids::uuid>*) ()
#3  0x08056367 in std::_Rb_tree<boost::uuids::uuid, boost::uuids::uuid, std::_Identity<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::less<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::allocator<boost::uuids::uuid> >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<boost::uuids::uuid>*) ()
#4  0x08056367 in std::_Rb_tree<boost::uuids::uuid, boost::uuids::uuid, std::_Identity<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::less<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::allocator<boost::uuids::uuid> >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<boost::uuids::uuid>*) ()
#5  0x08056367 in std::_Rb_tree<boost::uuids::uuid, boost::uuids::uuid, std::_Identity<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::less<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::allocator<boost::uuids::uuid> >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<boost::uuids::uuid>*) ()
#6  0x001ceb8c in vsdk::radius::CRadiusAttribute::~CRadiusAttribute() () from ./libRadiusHandler.so
#7  0x001d5a33 in vsdk::radius::CRadiusMsg::~CRadiusMsg() () from ./libRadiusHandler.so
#8  0x001d3509 in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<vsdk::radius::CRadiusClientReq*, vsdk::radius::CRadiusClientReq::Deleter>::dispose() () from ./libRadiusHandler.so
#9  0x08055d48 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() ()
#10 0x001d1eff in vsdk::radius::CRadiusClientHandler::handleRecv(ACE_INET_Addr const&, ACE_INET_Addr const&, ACE_Message_Block&, bool&) () from ./libRadiusHandler.so
#11 0x001e27ba in vsdk::radius::CUdpMsg::run() () from ./libRadiusHandler.so
#12 0x001c8a9c in vsdk::radius::CHandlerMgr::svc() () from ./libRadiusHandler.so
#13 0x00d55172 in ACE_Task_Base::svc_run (args=0x96f24d8) at Task.cpp:271
#14 0x00d56798 in ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke_i (this=0x9737168) at Thread_Adapter.cpp:161
#15 0x00d56835 in ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke (this=0x9737168) at Thread_Adapter.cpp:96
#16 0x00cefa31 in ace_thread_adapter (args=0x9737168) at Base_Thread_Adapter.cpp:122
#17 0x00aeba49 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#18 0x009fbaee in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Seems in `std::set<boost::uuids::uuid>`'s destructor. Why?

Here are my codes, some unimportant codes are omitted:

```
class CRadiusClientReq
{
private:
    CRadiusMsg      m_radiusMsg;            ///<    radius msg
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr< CRadiusClientReq >     CSpCRadiusClientReq;

class CRadiusMsg
{
private:
    static const uint32_t  MAX_ATTR_NUM = 23;
    CRadiusAttribute                                m_attributes[MAX_ATTR_NUM];
};

class CRadiusAttribute
{
private:
    EAttributeType                  m_type;
    uint32_t                        m_uint32;
    uint8_t                         m_array[CHAP_PASSWORD_LEN];
    std::string                     m_string;
    std::set< boost::uuids::uuid >  m_resSet;   // seems core dump in free this member
};

class CRadiusRequestRspWaitMgr
{
public:
    bool queryRequest( const uint8_t id, CSpCRadiusClientReq & spRadiusClientReq )
    {
        // lock 
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock  l( m_mutex );

        RadiusRequestRspWaitMap::iterator   itr = m_requestRspWaitMap.find( id );
        if ( m_requestRspWaitMap.end() == itr )
        {
            // not found
            return false;
        }

        spRadiusClientReq = itr->second;
        if ( !spRadiusClientReq )
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool delRequest( const uint8_t id )
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock  l( m_mutex );

        RadiusRequestRspWaitMap::iterator   itr = m_requestRspWaitMap.find( id );
        if ( m_requestRspWaitMap.end() == itr )
        {
            // not found
            return false;
        }

        // erase it
        m_requestRspWaitMap.erase( itr );

        return true;
    }

private:
    typedef std::map< uint8_t, CSpCRadiusClientReq>  RadiusRequestRspWaitMap;
    RadiusRequestRspWaitMap         m_requestRspWaitMap;    // requests which is waiting response.
    boost::mutex                    m_mutex;                //
};

class CRadiusClientHandler
{
private:
    CRadiusRequestRspWaitMgr   m_authReqRspWaitMgr; ///< auth rsp wait manager
    CRadiusRequestRspWaitMgr   m_acctReqRspWaitMgr; ///< acct rsp wait manager
};

void CRadiusClientHandler::handleRecv( const ACE_INET_Addr& localAddr, const ACE_INET_Addr& peer, ACE_Message_Block& msg, bool &bReuse )
{
    // set reuse this message block
    bReuse = true;

    uint8_t     *buf = (uint8_t*)msg.rd_ptr();
    uint32_t    len = msg.length();
    if ( len < 20 )
    {
        return;
    }

    // read code and id.
    uint8_t     code = buf[0];
    uint8_t     id = buf[1];

    CRadiusRequestRspWaitMgr    *rspWaitMgr = 0;
    if ( D_PACKET_ACCESS_ACCEPT == code
        || D_PACKET_ACCESS_REJECT == code )
    {
        // auth response

        if ( localAddr.get_port_number() != m_srcAuthPort )
        {
            // not auth port
            return;
        }

        // set rspWaitMgr
        rspWaitMgr = &m_authReqRspWaitMgr;
    }
    else if ( D_PACKET_ACCOUNTING_RESPONSE == code )
    {
        // acct response

        if ( localAddr.get_port_number() != m_srcAcctPort )
        {
            // not acct port
            return;
        }

        // set rspWaitMgr
        rspWaitMgr = &m_acctReqRspWaitMgr;
    }
    else
    {
        // error type msg
        return;
    }

    // find a match request in waiting response queue
    CSpCRadiusClientReq     spClientReq;
    if ( !rspWaitMgr->queryRequest( id, spClientReq )
        || !spClientReq )
    {
        return;
    }

    // some handle process code here, omitted.
    ...

    // delete request in waiting response queue
    rspWaitMgr->delRequest( id );
}

int32_t CUdpMsg::run()
{
    if ( !m_udpMsgNotify )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    bool    bReuse = true;

    m_udpMsgNotify->handleRecv( m_localAddr, m_srcAddr, *m_aceMb, bReuse );

    if ( bReuse )
    {
        delete m_aceMb;
        m_aceMb = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

// send request
bool CRadiusClientHandler::sendNonLoginAuthReq(const std::string & userName
                                , const uint8_t chapId
                                , const boost::array<uint8_t,16> & chapChallenge
                                , const boost::array<uint8_t,16> & pwdCaculated
                                , const boost::array<uint8_t,16> & uid
                                , const uint32_t authority
                                , const std::set<boost::uuids::uuid> & resIds
                                , uint8_t & authId
                                , EClientHandlerError & result)
{
    result = ECLIENTHANDLERERROR_FAIL;
    CSpCRadiusClientReq spRadiusClientReq( new CRadiusClientReq() );
    if ( !spRadiusClientReq )
    {
        return false;
    }

    CRadiusMsg &radiusMsg = spRadiusClientReq->getRadiusMsg();

    // set the boost
    if ( !radiusMsg.setResList( resIds ) )
    {
        result = ECLIENTHANDLERERROR_RESNUM_OVERTOP;
        return false;
    }


    // some other unimportant codes, include generate reqId, omitted.
    uint8_t     reqId = 0;
    ...


    // add to rspWaitMgr
    if ( !m_authReqRspWaitMgr.addRequest( reqId, spRadiusClientReq ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    // some other unimportant codes, include message sending,  omitted.
    ...


    // return reqId
    authId = reqId;
    result = ECLIENTHANDLERERROR_SUCCESS;
    return true;
}
```

`CRadiusClientHandler::handleRecv` handles a received udp packet. It finds a match request `spClientReq` in `rspWaitMgr` which is a pool of all requests which are waiting responses.

After `CRadiusClientHandler::handleRecv` finish and exit the scope, the `spClientReq` auto delete the pointer saved in this shared_ptr.

And I use the pointer all in shared_ptr. I think `boost::shared_ptr` is thread safe. So I can't see any double free.

In `CRadiusClientHandler` I have two member `m_authReqRspWaitMgr` and `m_acctReqRspWaitMgr`. According the type of message received, I choose to use which one.

So when this core dump happens, these two member are still exist. And I have only one instance of `CRadiusClientHandler` which will be deleted at exit of my program.

---

Here is my analysis.

These are the disassembled codes in _int_free:

```
   0x0098bff8 <+152>:   shr    $0x3,%edi
   0x0098bffb <+155>:   mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0098bffd <+157>:   sub    $0x2,%edi
   0x0098c000 <+160>:   mov    0x8(%eax,%edi,4),%edx
   0x0098c004 <+164>:   lea    0x8(%ecx,%edi,4),%ecx
   0x0098c008 <+168>:   mov    %edi,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x0098c00b <+171>:   cmp    %edx,%esi
   0x0098c00d <+173>:   je     0x98c514 <_int_free+1460>
   0x0098c013 <+179>:   mov    $0xffffffff,%edi
   0x0098c018 <+184>:   jmp    0x98c02a <_int_free+202>
   0x0098c01a <+186>:   nopw   0x0(%eax,%eax,1)
   0x0098c020 <+192>:   cmp    %eax,%esi
   0x0098c022 <+194>:   mov    %eax,%edx
   0x0098c024 <+196>:   je     0x98c514 <_int_free+1460>
   0x0098c02a <+202>:   test   %edx,%edx
   0x0098c02c <+204>:   je     0x98c037 <_int_free+215>
=> 0x0098c02e <+206>:   mov    0x4(%edx),%edi
   0x0098c031 <+209>:   shr    $0x3,%edi
   0x0098c034 <+212>:   sub    $0x2,%edi
   0x0098c037 <+215>:   mov    %edx,0x8(%esi)
   0x0098c03a <+218>:   mov    %edx,%eax
   0x0098c03c <+220>:   cmpl   $0x0,%gs:0xc
   0x0098c044 <+228>:   je     0x98c047 <_int_free+231>
   0x0098c046 <+230>:   lock cmpxchg %esi,(%ecx)
   0x0098c04a <+234>:   cmp    %eax,%edx
   0x0098c04c <+236>:   jne    0x98c020 <_int_free+192>
   0x0098c04e <+238>:   test   %edx,%edx
   0x0098c050 <+240>:   je     0x98c05b <_int_free+251>
   0x0098c052 <+242>:   cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%edi
   0x0098c055 <+245>:   jne    0x98c5a9 <_int_free+1609>
```

I try to match the source code in malloc.c(glibc-2.12.1), maybe here:

```
    set_fastchunks(av);
    unsigned int idx = fastbin_index(size);
    fb = &fastbin (av, idx);

#ifdef ATOMIC_FASTBINS
    mchunkptr fd;
    mchunkptr old = *fb;
    unsigned int old_idx = ~0u;
    do
      {
        /* Another simple check: make sure the top of the bin is not the
           record we are going to add (i.e., double free).  */
        if (__builtin_expect (old == p, 0))
          {
            errstr = "double free or corruption (fasttop)";
            goto errout;
          }
        if (old != NULL)
          old_idx = fastbin_index(chunksize(old));   **-------- maybe core dump here**
        p->fd = fd = old;
      }
    while ((old = catomic_compare_and_exchange_val_rel (fb, p, fd)) != fd);

    if (fd != NULL && __builtin_expect (old_idx != idx, 0))
      {
        errstr = "invalid fastbin entry (free)";
        goto errout;
      }
#else
    /* Another simple check: make sure the top of the bin is not the
       record we are going to add (i.e., double free).  */
    if (__builtin_expect (*fb == p, 0))
      {
        errstr = "double free or corruption (fasttop)";
        goto errout;
      }
    if (*fb != NULL
        && __builtin_expect (fastbin_index(chunksize(*fb)) != idx, 0))
      {
        errstr = "invalid fastbin entry (free)";
        goto errout;
      }

    p->fd = *fb;
    *fb = p;
#endif
```

It seems that the variable `old` point to a invalid address.

Registers info are:

```
(gdb) info register
eax            0xb5d00010       -1244659696
ecx            0xb5d00024       -1244659676
edx            0xb4304ce8       -1271903000
ebx            0xaabff4 11190260
esp            0xb6179a84       0xb6179a84
ebp            0xb6179ad8       0xb6179ad8
esi            0xb5d235e0       -1244514848
edi            0xffffffff       -1
eip            0x98c02e 0x98c02e <_int_free+206>
eflags         0x10286  [ PF SF IF RF ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51
(gdb) x /8xw 0xb4304ce8
0xb4304ce8:     Cannot access memory at address 0xb4304ce8
(gdb)
```

According to the source code and disassembled code, I have these conclusions:
-The `%eax` is the `av`.
-The `%ecx` is the `fb`.
-The `%edi` is the `old_idx`.
-The `%esi` is the memory chunk need to be free.

The `%edi` is still the initial value 0xFFFFFFFF, so I think this is the first time enter the loop.
According to `mchunkptr old = *fb`, maybe `%edx` equals the content of address `%ecx`.
But now, the `%edx`(`old`) is 0xb4304ce8, the content of address `%ecx`(`*fb`) is 0xb5d5a958. They are different.

```
(gdb) x /8xw 0xb5d00024
0xb5d00024:     0xb5d5a958      0xb5dc3088      0x00000000      0x00000000
0xb5d00034:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0xb45d9208
(gdb)
```

And I have noticed the `flags` in `av` is 0x00000002, it means no fastbin?

```
(gdb) x /8xw 0xb5d00010
0xb5d00010:     0x00000000      0x00000002      0x00000000      0xb5ddc848
0xb5d00020:     0xb5d5e4f8      0xb5d5a958      0xb5dc3088      0x00000000
(gdb)
```

And I also have noticed these comments:

```
/*
  FASTCHUNKS_BIT held in max_fast indicates that there are probably
  some fastbin chunks. It is set true on entering a chunk into any
  fastbin, and cleared only in malloc_consolidate.

  The truth value is inverted so that have_fastchunks will be true
  upon startup (since statics are zero-filled), simplifying
  initialization checks.
*/
```

So I think, after current thread execute `mchunkptr old = *fb;`, some other thread trigger `malloc_consolidate` to clean and consolidate chunks in fastbin.

Then maybe cause the memory point by `%edx` has been trimed or released. But is it possible?

I have little knowledge about the memory management of glibc, maybe some someone can relieve my suspicion.

Here is OS's information :

```
[root@mdssdk log]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
[root@mdssdk log]# uname -a
Linux mdssdk 2.6.32-358.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:48:01 EST 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@mdssdk log]#
```

---

Finally, I download glibc newest version 2.24, and found the real reason. This is a bug, and fixed in glibc 2.19.

Fixed code here:

```
set_fastchunks(av);
unsigned int idx = fastbin_index(size);
fb = &fastbin (av, idx);

/* Atomically link P to its fastbin: P->FD = *FB; *FB = P;  */
mchunkptr old = *fb, old2;
unsigned int old_idx = ~0u;
do
  {
    /* Check that the top of the bin is not the record we are going to add
       (i.e., double free).  */
    if (__builtin_expect (old == p, 0))
      {
        errstr = "double free or corruption (fasttop)";
        goto errout;
      }
    **/* Check that size of fastbin chunk at the top is the same as
       size of the chunk that we are adding.  We can dereference OLD
       only if we have the lock, otherwise it might have already been
       deallocated.  See use of OLD_IDX below for the actual check.  */**
    if (have_lock && old != NULL)
      old_idx = fastbin_index(chunksize(old));
    p->fd = old2 = old;
  }
while ((old = catomic_compare_and_exchange_val_rel (fb, p, old2)) != old2);

if (have_lock && old != NULL && __builtin_expect (old_idx != idx, 0))
  {
    errstr = "invalid fastbin entry (free)";
    goto errout;
  }
```

Comment: The problem should be in your code instead of `malloc` `boost` or `std::set`, it should be double free somewhere in `#10 0x001d1eff in vsdk::radius::CRadiusClientHandler::handleRecv` and `#11 0x001e27ba in vsdk::radius::CUdpMsg::run` and this is C++, not C

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: Sorry for error tag and sorry for bad code format. I copy it from malloc.c. And in these codes, tabs and spaces mixed, so It seems bad. I have reformat them. I have added some implemention code. I can't found any double free. Is't correct?

Comment: @JunHuang How do you initialize `CRadiusRequestRspWaitMgr    *rspWaitMgr` and how do you free it? It's the most important code, you can remove the code of `malloc`, there's no bug in that code

Comment: @Danh `CRadiusRequestRspWaitMgr *rspWaitMgr` point to the address of one member of `CRadiusClientHandler`.And `CRadiusClientHandler` only freed at exit of program.Codes has been updated, thank you!

Comment: The trace log indicates error when free `CSpCRadiusClientReq     spClientReq;` Can you check if `rspWaitMgr->queryRequest( id, spClientReq )` work as expected?

Comment: Run your code under valgrind or a similar tool. The core dump is showing the victim, not the perpetrator.

Comment: @Danh  I have run my code under valgrind, no memory error reports. And I have test code to test my function, these code can works well. So I think `rspWaitMgr->queryRequest` works as my excepted. And I also suspect some other codes corrupt the memory, but it happens only once during ten days. Is there any other methods to find out the reason?

Comment: @JunHuang From the trace, I think that `spClientReq` is double freed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contributing an answer to my problem.

I have found the real reason. Just like I suspect, there has a bug in the _int_free. It is fixed in glibc 2.19.

Here is the bug report.

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15073